# Borrar un objeto y otro no en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, index

Tengo este codigo que me regresa los nombres duplicados de un modelo, filtrados por nombre, apellido y fecha de nacimiento.

```
for member in miembros_con_nombres_duplicados:
        # Get all duplicates of this member
        duplicates = GroupMember.objects.filter(
            contact__first_name=member.contact.first_name,
            contact__last_name=member.contact.last_name,
            contact__date_born=member.contact.date_born,
            group_id=1
        ).order_by('id')
```

Me regresa los duplicados de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es al segundo duplicado aplicarle al función de borrado, ya intente con este codigo.

```
for index, member in enumerate(miembros_con_nombres_duplicados):
        print(index, miembros_con_nombres_duplicados[index+1])
        miembros_con_nombres_duplicados[index+1].delete()
```

pero no me funciona,me sigue trayendo todos los objetos, el unico que me brinca es el primero.

Como puedo hacer para borrar el segundo y dejar el primero?

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es filtrar el primer registro de cada valor duplicado así :

```
miembros_con_nombres_duplicados = GroupMember.objects.filter(
    group_id=1 ).values(
    'contact__first_name',
    'contact__last_name',
    'contact__date_born',).annotate(
    min_id=models.Min('id') ).order_by().filter(id__gt=models.F('min_id') 
)
```

y luego de eso recorres el arreglo y eliminas los registros excluyendo el registro encontrado :

```
for duplicate in miembros_con_nombres_duplicados:
GroupMember.objects.filter(
    contact__first_name=duplicate['contact__first_name'],
    contact__last_name=duplicate['contact__last_name'],
    contact__date_born=duplicate['contact__date_born'],
    group_id=1,  # Asegúrate de filtrar por el grupo correcto si es necesario
    id__gt=duplicate['min_id']).delete()
```